# Sorting - Is it ever possible to sort using subarrays well?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, runtime

I came across an array sorting algorithm that seems pretty good, however it recurses using sub-arrays. I heard the time complexity of making a sub-array is O(n), which more or less stops any efficient sort from using sub-arrays.

The algorithm:

Take a pivot. We'll call it the last number in the array every time for the purpose of demonstration.
Put the pivot in its correct place. Here, you would look at 2 and 6, and if 6 is greater, put it after 2. Then look at 1 and 2, and if it's less, put it on the left. If two numbers are equal, I chose to put the pivot on the left.
Take the sub-arrays on both the left and right side of the pivot and recur on those.
Stop when the sub-array size is one.

A worked example:

```
 6 1 7 8 6 9 1 2        Pivot would be 2
 1 1 2 6 6 7 8 9        Put 2 in it's place, time to take sub-arrays
[1 1] 2 [6 7 8 9]       Recur.
 1 1  2 [6 7 8] 9       Recur more. 
 1 1 2  [6 7] 8 9       Recur.
 1 1 2  6 7 8 9         Done!
```

What is the time complexity? Also, I'd be interested to see the time complexity if taking a subarray just takes O(1) time.

I think worst case this algorithm is O(n^2), but what is it average case?

Also please don't link a better sort, I'm trying to figure out a good sort on my own.

Comment: "making a sub-array" takes no time if you define the sub-array as (array, start-index, end-index), since you don't have to copy the data, you just limit yourself to work on a smaller part of the big array.

Comment: After reading `time to take sub-arrays`, the example works away one of the values - spooky.

Answer (score 1):

You have described the [Quick Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) algorithm, which has average time complexity of `O(n log n)` and worst case time complexity of `O(n^2)` (oddly enough when the array is already sorted).